# Does Yodlee send HTML-encoded data?

Tags: yodlee

We use Yodlee API to connect to banks for their transactional data. The problem we have is, all transactions that have ampersands (&) in their descriptions come as &amp; . Do we have to explicitly decode &amp; to & after receiving the response from Yodlee? How about other html entities?

(I couldn't find other forums where I could post this question--learned that Yodlee support is on Stack Overflow now?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to parse them explicitly because the response is in XML format and hence all escape characters like ampersands(&) will be passed appropriately or else the XML will not be in right format.

Here is the list of escape characters for XML -

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```